# Multi-Table Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm new to rails and I have some `has_many through:` relationships in my app.
I have `User, Message` and `Message_Recipients` models (a user has many messages, a message has one sender, a message has many recipients - message_recipients is the join table).

I am trying to show the message sender's name in my Message views, which is held in the User model. However, I am getting errors no matter what way I try to do this - I am unsure if I am even adhering to "the Rails Way".

User fields are: `id, forename, surname, email`

Message fields are: `id, sender_id, subject, body` *sender_id is a User FK*

Message_Recipient fields are: `id, user_id, message_id` *user/message_id are FKs*

Here are my models (I am also using Devise):

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "sender_id"#sender
  has_many :message_recipients
  has_many :users, through: :message_recipients
end



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :message_recipients
  has_many :messages, through: :message_recipients
end



class MessageRecipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message, :class_name => Message, :foreign_key => "message_id"
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

This is my messages/index.html.erb:

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <div class="message">
    <h2><%= message.subject %></h2>
    <p>Sent by <%= message.user.forename %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It is in the view that I'm having trouble as I can't seem to get the value of the forename of the user based on the sender_id of the person who sent the message, due to getting a NoMethodError.

Any help/best practice advice will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associations can be tricky enough without overthinking them. You need only two models, users and messages.
Messages table would contain the title, text, recipient_id and sender_id. (sounds like the sender would select from a dropdown list of recipients in the database. Upon selection that person's user_id would be flagged, and the current_user's user_id would be set for the sender's id the other field: Example
Message.create((id will be automatic) sender(current_user user_id) recipient (user_id), text: "Have a nice day")
in user model: has and belongs to messages; in the messages model: belongs to user.
Try it out in your console.

Comment: would this work for a message sent to multiple users though? Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: Yes, look up how to save to an array of user_ids (you're using postgresql, right?)

Comment: I'm using sqlite3, will it be the same do you think? Thanks very much

Comment: Frankly, I don't know, but it's not difficult to move up to postgresql. Are these im's you're sending? If yes, and you're using Rails 5, you may want to check out some tutorials on ActiveCable (I know nothing about it; never looked at a tutorial on it). It might be the answer to all these questions.